# Why bq76940 cell0 has two capacitors

Tags: lipo, cell-balancing

I'm exploring bq76940 datasheet. I've found such typical scheme for cells connection:

[image: bq76920 cells connection]

Why VC5-VC4, VC4-VC3, VC3-VC2, VC2-VC1 pairs have only one capacitor and VC1-VC0 pair has two capacitors? What is the purpose of all these elements in this scheme?

Comment: VC0 and VC1 do not have a pair of capacitors ... look at the schematic again ... VC0 has only one capacitor ... in fact, the capacitor on VC0 is incorrectly drawn, contrary to convention

Comment: Do you mean that it's an error in datasheet and correct schematic should look like this https://postimg.cc/TpKcmf03 ?

Comment: no, that is not what i am saying ... i did not say that the capacitor on VC1 is incorrectly drawn

Comment: In this case I still can't understand you point, sorry :(

Comment: in fact, the bottom Rc and bottom Cc are not part of the ladder network, so they should have been drawn elsewhere

Comment: Would you please tell me, why bottom Rc and Cc are not part of the ladder network? What is the purpose of this network? What kind of noise should it filter?

Comment: both of those components are connected to ground